# Find largest circle that fits within a set of points given a starting point (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, linear-algebra, computational-geometry

Given a starting point `(82, 186)` and a collection of surrounding points `[(105, 186), (95, 157), (81, 159), (64, 173), (52, 188), (127, 195)]`, how can I determine the largest circle that will fit within those points?

Note: The center need not be the starting point

```
cX, cY = (82, 186)
points = [(105, 186), (95, 157), (81, 159), (64, 173), (52, 188), (127, 195)]

def closest_node(node, nodes):
    nodes = np.asarray(nodes)
    deltas = nodes - node
    dist = np.linalg.norm(deltas, axis=1)
    min_idx = np.argmin(dist)
    return nodes[min_idx], dist[min_idx], deltas[min_idx][1]/deltas[min_idx][0]  # point, distance, slope

(pX, pY), d, m = closest_node((cX, cY), points)
cv2.circle(img, (cX, cY), int(d), (255, 0, 255), 1)  # circle with center C, touching point P

# learning rate
a = 0.2

# sign for direction
sX = 1 if cX - pX > 0 else -1
sY = 1 if cY - pY > 0 else -1

dx = (d * a) * np.sqrt(1 / (1 + m**2))

# New center
nX = cX + sX * dx
nY = cY + sY * m * dx
cv2.circle(img, (int(nX), int(nY)), int(d + (d * a)), [0, 0, 0], 1)
```

So I am trying to approach the second point iteratively (and then the third) but I think it would be better if there was a **vectorized approach**. How can I do this?

EDIT: A solution using Voronoi

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi

points = np.array(points)

if len(points) >= 4:

    vor = Voronoi(points)

    max_d = 0
    max_v = None
    for v in vor.vertices:
        cv2.circle(img, (int(v[0]), int(v[1])), 3, [200, 200, 0], 1)
        _, d, _ = closest_node(v, points)
        if d > max_d:
            max_d = d
            max_v = v

    cv2.circle(img, (int(max_v[0]), int(max_v[1])), int(max_d), [0, 0, 0], 1)
```

Comment: What _is_ the starting point if not the center? Just another point? If so, why isn't it in the list? And why are you calling it `cx` and `cy` if it's not the center?

Comment: Uhh did you mean find the smallest circle containing all points instead? Because otherwise you can always find a larger circle far away from all points...

Comment: @Julien I just tried your answer... nice one but I am looking for the largest inscribed circle as suggested below, not the smallest enclosing circle :)

Comment: This is ill defined, unless you specify clearly how the desired solution is bound to the starting point.

Comment: It's not bound to the starting point, but I just happen to know that the starting point would be within the region that would contain the largest circle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is problem of finding the [largest inscribed circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_empty_sphere) (while its center lies inside convex hull of point cloud).

It [might be solved](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/cs97/s08/papers/schuster.pdf) using Voronoi diagram in O(nlogn) time.

For python - scipy contains [Voronoi routine](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html)

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a shot

Comment: That worked reasonably well, although sometimes it selects a circle outside of the region with my "starting point". Is there any way to constrain this or should I just do an "in-circle" test with my "starting point"?

Comment: Perhaps you can check what Voronoi cell contains your starting point and choose it